# convert expression into the string describing its type in haskell script?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

We all know that `:t` in `ghci` gives the type of an expression:

```
Prelude> :t [1..]
[1..] :: (Enum t, Num t) => [t]
```

What I need is an equivalent of `:t` in haskell script(I'll call it `typeStr`) :

```
main = putStrLn $ typeStr [1..]
```

that can print something like `(Enum t, Num t) => [t]` on screen.

Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What's your underlying problem?

Comment: Just have interest in how to do this, I'd like to write a helper function that can give the result of an expression as well as its type.

Comment: If you only want to use this function in ghci, you should run `:set +t` at the ghci prompt: it will subsequently tell you the types of expressions you enter when normally it would only tell you their values.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it does help in repl, but not in source file. The compiler might complain since (I guess) it knows nothing about `:t` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways.

**1. Use dynamic typing**

For the simple case of monomorphic types, you can use the Typeable instance:

```
Data.Dynamic> typeOf [1..]
[Integer]
```

**2. Use runtime evaluation**

However, to do this properly - to get the type of polymorphic values - you'll need the full GHC type checker. E.g. via the ghc-api library, and its nice wrapper, [hint](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hint/latest/doc/html/Language-Haskell-Interpreter.html#v:typeOf):

```
Language.Haskell.Interpreter> runInterpreter $ typeOf "[1..]"
Right "(P.Enum t, P.Num t) => [t]"
```

Which is the correctly inferred type using the full GHC type checker, invoked dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, as long as the type is an instance of `Data.Typeable`:

```
import Data.Typeable
typeStr :: Typeable a => a -> String
typeStr a = show $ typeOf a
```

I don't think you're going to get the most general type possible however, since the argument will be of a specific type.  For instance, `typeStr [1..]` yields `[Integer]` in ghci.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Haskell generally doesn't allow you to write expressions who's type is unknown until runtime, so there's never any need for a run-time type lookup in the first place.

Having said that, there *are* ways to do dynamic typing, and plausibly that might support printing a type signature... but this is probably not what you want to do at all.

Another possibility is to use Template Haskell to look up the type signature at compile-time. I don't know if anybody has already written the code for that yet...